# How to update map value using function?

Tags: clojure

I have a map `m`, a key `k` and a function `f`. Is it possible to rewrite this code simpler?

```
(assoc m k (f (get m k))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [clojure.core/update-in](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/update-in)

```
(update-in m [k] f)
```

Edit: Clojure 1.7 introduced [clojure.core/update](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/update)

```
(update m k f)
```

Answer (score 4):

update-in does this nicely, though it's especially useful for nested maps:

```
> (update-in {:a 4} [:a] + 7)
{:a 11}

> (update-in {:a {:b 4 :c {:d 8}} :q :foo} [:a :c :d] + 7) 
{:a {:c {:d 15}, :b 4}, :q :foo}
```